# Is it abuse of notation to write the hessian as $D^2f$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, hessian-matrix

The hessian matrix of a function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is often written as $D^2f=D(Df)$. However, as far as I know, $D$ is an operator that takes a function, and returns a matrix of functions ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_matrix)). Therefore, if the inner $D$ in $D(Df)$ maps the function $f$ to a matrix of functions, the outer $D$ can not take that result as an argument, since it is not a function.

So is $D^2f$ for the hessian matrix an abuse of notation? Or am I missing something? (I'd like to see how this is correct from an exact definition of $D$, but I can't find one).

Comment: $D^2$ is ambiguous because we don't know which is inner or outer product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L(V,W)$ denote the vector space of linear maps from (vector space) $V$ to (vector space) $W$. Note that $Df\colon\Bbb R^n\to L(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R)$ is likewise a function (which assigns to $x$ the linear map $Df(x)$), and you're differentiating this. Thus, $D(Df)(x)$ is a linear map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $L(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R)$, which is, in turn, a bilinear map from $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$. This is what the usual hessian matrix representation is.

Comment: So the hessian matrix should not be seen as equal to the object $D^2f$, but as a matrix representation of $D^2f$?

Comment: Well, but remember your usual derivative matrix is likewise the representation of a linear map with respect to the standard bases.

Comment: I've been looking at this some more: Wouldn't it be more correct to state that $D^2f(x)$ is shorthand for $D[\nabla f(x)]$, i.e. $D[(Df(x))^T]$? Because if you look at the shape of $D[Df(x)]$ as an "array": $Df(x)$  is a row vector, i.e. a member of the dual space of the domain of $f$. if $D$ acts on that dual space, it would give us a vector in the dual of the dual of the domain of $X$. The dual of the dual of $V$ is technically not the same as $V$ itself. Do you agree therefore that technically, $D[Df(x)]$ is abuse of notation?

Comment: No, the derivative of a mapping to a vector space is a linear map *to* that vector space, so you're not quite right. The thing to chase down is how you associate a bilinear form on $\Bbb R^n$ with an $n\times n$ matrix. (Symmetry is a deeper calculus fact here.)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you may regard $D$ as a tensorial product. That is,
$$
Df=\nabla\otimes f,
$$
and
$$
D^2f=D\left(Df\right)=\nabla\otimes\left(\nabla\otimes f\right)=\left(\nabla\otimes\nabla\right)\otimes f.
$$
In the coordinate representation, the above expressions read
\begin{align}
\left(Df\right)_{\mu\nu}&=\partial_{\mu}f_{\nu},\\
\left(D^2f\right)_{\mu\nu\sigma}&=\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}f_{\sigma},
\end{align}
where $\left(Df\right)_{\mu\nu}$ means the $\left(\mu,\nu\right)$-th entry of the matrix $Df$, while $\left(D^2f\right)_{\mu\nu\sigma}$ stands for the $\left(\mu,\nu,\sigma\right)$-th entry of the tensor $D^2f$.